# How to override variables that contain string of digits in Kubernetes config file for spring boot app?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

In our Spring Boot application, we have variables in our `application.yml` file that are defined as below.

*src/resources/application.yml*

```
site:
  "8964":
     type: "SHOPS"
     size: 10
  "5634"
     type: "STADIUMS"
     size: 20
```

And, I have tried to override them in `k8s`(kubernetes) config file by trying two different possible (below) ways as we follow the same practice(format) in our team:

*k8s/dev/config.yaml*

```
SITE_"8964"_TYPE : "SHOPS"
SITE_"8964"_SIZE : 99
SITE_"5634"_TYPE : "STADIUMS"
SITE_"5634"_SIZE : 88
```

or

```
SITE_'8964'_TYPE : "SHOPS"
SITE_'8964'_SIZE : 99
SITE_'5634'_TYPE : "STADIUMS"
SITE_'5634'_SIZE : 88
```

However, it doesn't seem like the sites ids (eg. "8964") although they were wrapped with single or double quotes. I wonder what else I can do to make the ids to be read as string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://env.simplestep.ca/) online converter suggests to add a double underscore.

```yaml
site:
  "8964":
     type: "SHOPS"
     size: 10
  "5634":
     type: "STADIUMS"
     size: 20
```

converts to

```
SITE__5634_TYPE=STADIUMS
SITE__5634_SIZE=20
SITE__8964_TYPE=SHOPS
SITE__8964_SIZE=10
```